# Node.js - Error: Cannot find module 'config/chgpass'

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I created the files following the tutorial (http://dataops.co/android-login-registration-system-with-node-js-and-mongodb/), but unfortunately the error is shown like in the image.
I'm new to node.js and to this kind of programming.

PS.: All of the other files that are referred in the tutorial are right, and the chgpass.js is in the target folder.

Code from the file that requests the chgpass.js file AND the tree from the folder (open with Word and select MS-DOS):
http://www.mediafire.com/download/w283nsjuuj9j794/File-Folder.txt

Comment: Cand you post the line of code that fires the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your config folder is inside of node_modules folder, thus use:

```
var chgpass = require('config/chgpass');
```

Explanation:

- In tutorial config folder is inside node_modules that way you can directly access it using `require('config/chgpass')`
- But if you put outside of node_modules then you have to give the complete path of the folder from the location you are requiring it. That is in your case: `require('../config/chgpass')`

Comment: Even with "var chgpass = require('../config/chgpass');" it gives the same error. I inserted the full path too and it "brakes" with the same error

Comment: can you show your folder structure and the code of your .js file where you are requiring it.

Comment: The file with all of the info that you required it's on the question now. Please take a look at it.

Comment: seems you have changed the folder structure, and now i see your *config* folder is inside of *node_modules* folder, thus use: ```var chgpass = require('config/chgpass');```

Comment: True, it solved my problem! Thanks, please post the answer